# Do we need a post notice for possibly controversial questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

According to this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302609/300001), the SE staff has implemented for a couple of communities a post notice for sensitive, possibly controversial topics.

The notice recites:

> Controversial Post — You may use comments ONLY to suggest improvements. You may use answers ONLY to provide a solution to the specific question asked above. Moderators will remove debates, arguments or opinions **without notice**.

We sometimes receive questions about gender issues, harassment etc. that generate many debates: Would such a notice be useful for our community as well?

Comment: I would add a note saying why this notice has been added. Something like "In the past, other questions about {race,gender} have been derailed in the comments."

Comment: OMG, this is about trigger warnings??? Please DONT,

Comment: @SSimon no, it's not, but feel free to believe otherwise.

Comment: @barbecue lets vote

Comment: @SSimon We are already voting. The answers down below are in favour of such a feature: upvote them if you want it implemented; downvote them if you don't.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I dont understand? this is official voting??? really? why not polling? it is better..

Comment: @SSimon The title asked a precise question: _Do we need a post notice for possibly controversial questions?_ Two people answered that, yes, it'd be useful to have it, and several other people approved. If you don't want such a notice, write your own answer, explaining your reasons. That's the poll, as "official" as any other meta post. If you want a more explicit, separate poll, write it yourself, but it will be probably closed as duplicate of this one.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I would suggest poll since 12 ppl are not representative of the whole community.

Comment: @SSimon I don't know what you have in mind for an "official" poll, but there's no way other than writing a post here to make a poll. People who are interested in the development of the community usually participate in meta. Those who didn't vote probably simply don't care whether this feature is implemented or not. If you look around, you will see that for many other decisions the voting rate is similar.

Comment: @SSimon 12 ppl is a pretty good response for us on meta. Especially when the voting skews to +14/-1.

Comment: @StrongBad is decision made yet?

Comment: @SSimon we now have the above example mentioned post notice. As for how and when mods will use it, it will probably be reserved for the worst case scenarios to make it easier for users to understand why their comments were moved/deleted. I doubt it will change eour behavior much. I tested it out on https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102698/upset-by-male-classmates-openly-comparing-female-students-according-to-physical if you want to ask a new meta question about when it should be used.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I wasnt clear. @StrongBad what is decision on OP question? Is there will be such a notice?

Comment: @SSimon yes, diamond mods now have the post notice that the OP requested.

Comment: @aparente001 Uh, what's wrong with "recites"?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - You can recite poetry, for example.  Check a dictionary.  If you're still in doubt -- post a question at ELU and ping me.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm not a native English speaker, but I choose the words carefully and I know well what _to recite_ means. And dictionaries confirm that can be used also for texts other than poems. I'm happy to have mistakes fixed, but please don't make stylistic changes.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - Why don't you post at ELU then?  I checked a dictionary to make sure of my edit.  However, you apparently found a dictionary that you feel backs up your point of view.  The folks at ELU will help us straighten this out!

Comment: @aparente001 If you want to ask a question about this on ELU, please, go on.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - Seeing as it's you, I will attempt to construct something useful (a little later).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I like reads better than recites. I wouldn't say recites is wrong, or even unclear, but I think Americans would say reads.

Comment: @StrongBad Most of the times, I'd write "reads", but sometimes – like in this case – I'd write "recites". I don't think we should flatten out our writing style by using just the most common forms.

Comment: @aparente001 I apologize for my brusque reply, but it was late and I don't like to be told "Check a dictionary". I work with words and I routinely check dictionaries, several times a day. I certainly make mistakes, as anyone else, and I'm happy when I see my mistakes fixed (I actually think that my posts here get too few edits, I certainly make many mistakes).

Comment: I'm not a big fan of ELU: it's a community that struggles to reach an equilibrium, and I find the answers about word choice not particularly impressive. That's why I'm not interested in asking there (I like ELL more), but I'll happily discuss my choice of words in our chat room if you wish.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - Sure, ELL it is. Here's the new question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/155543/18523

Comment: So far, this feature seems to be helping. See [my post on meta Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3671/73).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would expect that such labels should be applied rarely, if at all. But it wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing to have the option available to us.

Comment: I'm taking this as a "yes I want this", which is why I upvoted. FWIW, over just the past few months I've seen quite a few questions that could have used this notice.

Comment: Feel free to just ping me if/when you have occasion to use this. Takes very little time or effort to add. aeismail, @eykanal

Comment: I upvoted this answer instead of the one by xLeitix because I don't believe such a label should be applied "aggressively", but I do think that "rarely, if at all" is underestimating it.

Comment: By "rarely," I mean on a small percentage of posts. But if we're running into that problem daily or even weekly, we'll need to take stock about what's going on.

Comment: I'd say that the consensus tends toward the implementation of the notice. Shall we have to ping Shog9, or you have already asked?

Comment: I'm assuming that in "Controversial Post — You may use comments ONLY to suggest improvements" the 'suggest improvements' bit also allows for 'requests for clarification'? A strict interpretation does not allow for asking for clarification, currently.

Comment: What's the best way to suggest that a post be declared controversial?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, please add this. And no, I don't think we should add this sparingly. I would propose to aggressively add this to questions that have a potential to be controversial. If used too much it does not matter (the warning does not say anything that's not true for all questions anyway), and if it salvages just a few questions that would otherwise get derailed it's a win.

(OTOH it will *only* help if the diamond mods actually *do* end up aggressively removing argumentative answers and comments without notice, as the warning would indicate - in my opinion this has not really been the case in the past)

Comment: “in my opinion this has not really been the case in the past”. It actually is... and not only comments that are argumentative, but any comments that are not liked by them. If you look at HNQ on Academia.SE, Travel.SE or Interpersonal.SE you can see a constant show of mods deleting whatever comment they stumble across. Except theirs, of course.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Here moderation is fairly unaggressive with respect to other communities, and our mods tend to remove comments only exceptionally when there are flags (see this [chat discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2496?m=38689083#38689083)). And the last sentence is definitely unwarranted for this community (yes, I'm quite happy of the mod team here ;-) ).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I am also quite happy of the mod team here. Saying that they delete comments does not necessarily mean there is something wrong with it. Of course the situation is quite worse on Travel or Interpersonal, but Academia doesn't rank so bad **wrt HNQs** as was originally mentioned.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto What's HNQ? Anyway, personally I have never really understood why people get so hung up on deleted comments - y'know, them being defined as volatile and so on ...

Comment: @xLeitix Hot Network Question. About comment deletion, it depends on the context: for instance, on Electronics.SE, I once wrote a comment pointing out that a certain answer was technically wrong and the discussion was later moved to chat. I think that comments that point out potential mistakes should not be moved because most of the readers don't check the chats. Usually, this kind of moderation reduces my interest in a community.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano indeed. Not to mention mods who prune all the comments and then bash at you if you ask for clarification that was "already asked" (according to them). Then they go on pruning your comment but leaving their rant against you.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I feel the spirit of Stack Exchange is that you should post your own competing answer rather than post meta-info about an existing answer in a comment. Personally, I feel more aggressive deleting of comments, maybe even automatically after some time, would actually *help* in the way that it would train us all that comments are indeed not meant to be permanent. At the moment comments are in a weird state where they usually stick around but sometimes get deleted (for usually not very clear rules), and then people like Andrea seem to get mad.

Comment: @xLeitix If there is already a correct answer, there's no need to post another one, but technically certain answers can be subtly (very) wrong and non-experts might not be able to catch the error, especially if the answer comes from a high-rep user. Comments can have an important function, and regardless of their original temporary status, I think they should be deleted with care.

Comment: The main issue is that, afaik, mod tools don't allow much flexibility in handling comments.

Comment: @xLeitix Usually yes, but sometimes you know an answer is wrong but can't find the correct answer yourself.

Comment: @xLeitix "for usually not very clear rules" partially yes, but what I dislike the most is that I could even start to recognize *some specific mods* in *some communities* who I know would delete a lot more comments than others. It looks like these few people don't care if comments are being left to add a contribution (whether it's an edit suggestion or a clarification request) but they just want to pick what stays.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto - I agree there is a serious problem with SE.  The moderation style varies so much from one site to another.  I have participated on a site where moderators delete comments without warning because they should have been posted as an answer, deletes answers because they should have been a comment, edits answers until they are unrecognizable because ... well, I have no idea why.  And if you contact SE with an objection, lo and behold, you are banished for a year fro mthat site.  When your year is up, you try again to try to understand their "rules," but they ...

Comment: ... pounce on the slightest infraction in order to ban you for another year.

Comment: @aparente001: Does that site to which you refer to happen to start with an "I"?

Comment: @user21820 Parenting Beta.